# Сохранение картинки с оригинальным именем

Tags: php, sql

Имеется такой код. `

```
    require_once 'upload.php';

    class validation {

    public function check_name_length($object) {

        if (mb_strlen($object->file['original_filename']) > 25) {

            $object->set_error('File name is too long.');

        }

    }

}


if (!empty($_FILES['test'])) {

    $upload = Upload::factory('public/materials');
    $upload->file($_FILES['test']);

    $validation = new validation;

    $upload->callbacks($validation, array('check_name_length'));

    $results = $upload->upload();

    var_dump($results);

}

?>


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="test" /> 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit me" />

</form>`
```

Дело в том , что я хочу сохранять картинки в формате .jpg и с оригинальным именем чтобы можно было их оттуда доставать, как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задавать уникальные имена картинкам используя `uniqid()`, а потом эти имена вместе с расширением, а так же, если надо, путем сохранять в БД. Не понятно что у вас за класс `Upload`, но через стандартные методы будет выглядеть вот так:

```
$fileExt = explode('.', $_FILE['file']['name'])  // Получаем расширение файла 

$fileName = uniqid("image_") . ".{$fileExt}";  // Создаем уникальное имя 

move_uploaded_file($_FILE['file']['tmp_name'], $path . $fileName)  // Сохраняем файл
```

---

Сохранять в бд надо переменную `$fileName`. Структура таблицы примерно такая:

```sql
CREATE TABLE api.image (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  alias VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

`alias` тут вы задаете сами, к примеру можно назвать не `alias`, а `userId`, и привязывать картинку к пользователю. Потом ее тянуть примерно так:

```sql
SELECT i.path from image i WHERE i.userId = 1;
```

Comment: Уникид юзанул, но дело сейчас вот в чем, как мне их позвать когда надо будет, ибо я не знаю какой ид ему приписали.

Comment: Сохраняйте в бд переменную `$fileName`, и потом из бд тяните.

Comment: Если вам не будет сложно, можете полусловом обяснить как?

Comment: Правил ответ, смотрите в ответе